# Truncated Chemical Names

Tags: statistics

*[Note: this question has also been posted on [KNIME](https://forum.knime.com/t/chemical-names/27644)]*

Good Morning,

I am currently researching treatment options for the Corona Virus from the CAS COVID-19 Antiviral Candidate Compounds Dataset available on the [www.CAS.org](http://www.CAS.org). One issue we have run into is that the Chemical Names of the Antiviral Compounds in the Dataset are truncated as depicted in the example below. We will be needing the entire Chemical Names for Downstream Analysis. Is there anyway we can obtain the complete/ untruncated Chemical Names of the Antiviral Compounds?

***Example of an Antiviral Agent with a truncated Chemical Name***

```
Acetamide 2-amino-N-(1-tricyclo[3.3.1.137]dec-1-ylethyl)-
  Mrv1921 09212018412D          

 17 19  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8517   -1.6585    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1163   -2.0322    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.5657   -1.2419    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.3012   -1.6156    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.0368   -1.2419    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.5873   -2.0322    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.0368   -0.4945    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.3012   -0.1208    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8517   -0.9111    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.5657   -0.4945    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  1  0  0  0  0
  4  5  1  0  0  0  0
  3  6  2  0  0  0  0
  1  7  1  0  0  0  0
  1  8  1  0  0  0  0
  8  9  1  0  0  0  0
  9 10  1  0  0  0  0
 10 11  1  0  0  0  0
 11 12  1  0  0  0  0
 12 13  1  0  0  0  0
  8 13  1  0  0  0  0
 15 17  1  0  0  0  0
 14 15  1  0  0  0  0
 15 16  1  0  0  0  0
  8 16  1  0  0  0  0
 12 14  1  0  0  0  0
 10 17  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using SMILES or Inkeys not human readable names regardless of whether they are IUPAC valid.